# Cannot set __ANDROID__ Symbol with NDK Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, android-ndk, symbols

I am trying to compile one of the Android NDK samples, specifically "native-activity".  I created a Project for this sample in Eclipse using the "Android Project from Existing Code" option, and then converting it to native using the "Android Tools -> Add Native Support" option from the Project Menu.

Unfortunately, when I build I get the following error:

Type 'EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY' could not be resolved

I have searched around for this problem, and what most people say is that `"__ANDROID__"` needs to be defined during the compile.  The advice is to add this as a Symbol from the "C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols" window in the Project Properties.

But my problem is that I don't actually have a "Symbols" tab in "Paths and Symbols".  I do have it for other C++ Projects ( non NDK ), but I don't have it here.

[image]

I am guessing this has to do with the way that the NDK Plugin for Eclipse works.  Is there any other way to get this Symbol defined with the options here?  Or do I need to find a different way to add C++ support to the Android Project that gives me the "Symbols" tab?

Comment: Do you see this problem during ndk-build step, or during indexing?

Comment: Not sure what "indexing" means exactly, but it appears this is NOT an issue with the ndk-build ( the .so builds fine ), it is only a problem with the Eclipse Code Analysis.  If I turn the "Type cannot be resolved" error to a warning, it will let me launch the app.  Kinda hacky, but I can live with it for now...?

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest way around. Often, starting new workspace gets the project right, but sometimes it does not.

Comment: I'm having the same issue of missing symbols tab. Hope we can get an answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue with the missing `Symbols` tab, I finally started poking around and discovered that the tabs are different for every toolchain. The Android GCC toolchain in particular does not have a `symbols` tab for some reason. (seems like a bug to me)

To change the current toolchain:
Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor

I had to uncheck `Display compatible toolchains only`
Then I chose the option `Cygwin GCC`
and set `Current builder` to `Android Builder`

The `symbols` tab now shows up.

As far as I can tell everything seems to be working the same as it was with the Android GCC toolchain. If there are any bad side effects to this approach, I am unaware of what they are. If I find anything, I will come back and update my answer.

Comment: I simply switched the toolchain to Cygwin, set the `__ANDROID__` symbol and switched the toolchain back to Android GCC. Still does the trick!

Answer (score -1):

Excuse me about my spelling mistakes, I am student and I study English now. My project has the same problem. I had to spend all day to find solution :). In your root project folder you need to open file ".cproject"  and add the following text:

```
<option IS_BUILTIN_EMPTY="false" IS_VALUE_EMPTY="false" id="com.android.gcc.option.definedSymbols.156386137" superClass="com.android.gcc.option.definedSymbols" valueType="definedSymbols">
                                    <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="__ANDROID__=0"/>
</option>
```

I do not know what the numbers mean in the end of ID section, but I freely changed them and everything was OK.

This text adds symbol `__ANDROID__`. Moreover tab "Symbols" becomes visible:

[image: This text adds symbol <code>__ANDROID__</code>. Moreover tab "Symbols" becomes visible]

Notice that `__ANDROID__` has value 0. You can check it if you open Preferences->C/C++ General/Path and Symbols/Symbols (now it is here)

Proof of appearing `__Symbols__` section in Eclipse:

[image: Proof of appearing <code>__Symbols__</code> section in Eclipse]

Finally, a chunk of my `__.cproject__` file:

```
<storageModule moduleId="cdtBuildSystem" version="4.0.0">
    <configuration artifactName="${ProjName}" buildProperties="" description="" id="com.android.toolchain.gcc.665394794" name="Default" optionalBuildProperties="" parent="org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.emptycfg">
        <folderInfo id="com.android.toolchain.gcc.665394794.1631346437" name="/" resourcePath="">
            <toolChain id="com.android.toolchain.gcc.1551434208" name="Android GCC" superClass="com.android.toolchain.gcc">
                <targetPlatform binaryParser="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ELF" id="com.android.targetPlatform.1128161810" isAbstract="false" superClass="com.android.targetPlatform"/>
                <builder id="com.android.builder.1391955059" keepEnvironmentInBuildfile="false" managedBuildOn="false" name="Android Builder" superClass="com.android.builder">
                    <outputEntries>
                        <entry flags="VALUE_WORKSPACE_PATH|RESOLVED" kind="outputPath" name=""/>
                    </outputEntries>
                </builder>
                <tool id="com.android.gcc.compiler.541863979" name="Android GCC Compiler" superClass="com.android.gcc.compiler">
                    <option IS_BUILTIN_EMPTY="false" IS_VALUE_EMPTY="false" id="com.android.gcc.option.includePath.156366136" superClass="com.android.gcc.option.includePath" valueType="includePath">
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="&quot;C:\Frameworks\androidndk\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include&quot;"/>
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="&quot;C:\MinGW\include&quot;"/>
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="&quot;C:\Frameworks\androidndk\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib\gcc\arm-linux-androideabi\4.9.x\include&quot;"/>
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="&quot;C:\Frameworks\androidndk\sources\android\native_app_glue&quot;"/>
                    </option>
                    <option IS_BUILTIN_EMPTY="false" IS_VALUE_EMPTY="false" id="com.android.gcc.option.definedSymbols.156386137" superClass="com.android.gcc.option.definedSymbols" valueType="definedSymbols">
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="__ANDROID__=0"/>
                    </option>
                    <inputType id="com.android.gcc.inputType.661587658" superClass="com.android.gcc.inputType"/>
                </tool>
            </toolChain>
        </folderInfo>
        <sourceEntries>
            <entry flags="VALUE_WORKSPACE_PATH|RESOLVED" kind="sourcePath" name="jni"/>
        </sourceEntries>
    </configuration>
</storageModule>
```

Hope this information will be useful.